# Vue 3 composition API, inject only works inside defineProps

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, inject

Here's the way I create my component:

```
  const app = createApp({
    template: `
      <${componentName} />
    `,
  });

  app.provide('componentId', 'the component id');
  app.component(componentName, App);
  app.mount(element);
```

so the componentId is provided in the app creation.

Then inside my component I do:

```
<script setup>
...
const props = defineProps({
  componentId: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    default: () => {
      return inject('componentId');
    },
  },
});
...
```

```
onMounted(async () => {
  console.log('props componentId', props.componentId); // the component id
  console.log('inject componentId', inject('componentId')); // undefined
});
```

What I don't understand is why when I use the onMounted the injected value is undefined, but using the props.componentId the value gets the correct value.

Why is that?

I tried using:
`inject('componentId')`
I expected:
'a component id'
But I got:
`undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-dependency-injection.html#inject) of `inject()`:

> Similar to lifecycle hook registration APIs, inject() must be called synchronously during a component's setup() phase.

The `onMounted()` hook is triggered after the setup() phase, so `inject()` is not working.